# How to edit Views results using postExecute in a field handler?

Tags: views, 8

I have a custom field handler which returns JSON data, and I would like to alter the output prior to the render() function in the handler. This is mainly for the purpose of compatibility with another module, which is using the handler's query results directly. After looking through the Views source code, I see that I need to call postExecute for the handler, as we are trying to set the appropriate data before it is used to create $this->view->result.

Currently, I have the following, but it does not seem to set the data as expected (trying to get the field to output 'hi' as a test)

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function postExecute(&$values) {
  foreach ($values as $value) {
    $ent = $this->relationship ? $value->_relationship_entities['entity_type'] : $value->_entity;
    $ent->set('field_name', array('value' => 'hi'));

    if ($this->relationship) {
      $values[$value->index]->_relationship_entities['entity_type'] = $ent;
    }
    else {
      $values[$value->index]->_entity = $ent;
    }
  }
}
```

How could I modify the returned query values in this step?

Comment: $values passed by reference, so try to modified it self.

Comment: if you want just modify values before render, have you tried   hook_views_pre_render . https://api.drupal.org/comment/62573#comment-62573